# filter custom columns(having values from custom methods in model) in CGridView

Tags: php, yii

Below is my code in view.php file

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id' => 'myGrid',
        'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
        'filter' => $model,
        'enableSorting' => true,
        'columns' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'id',
                'header' => 'ID',
                'value' => $data->id,                
            ),
            array(
                'header' => 'Value', 
                'value' => '$data->getValue($data->id)', //getValue($id) is a custom method in the model.php file which returns a value after some calculations                    
                'filter' => $model->listOfFilterValues(), //listOfFilterValues() is a custom method in the model.php file which returns a CHtml::listData
            ),            
        ),
       )
    );
```

As you can observe, I am using a custom method in model.php file to get the Value column(because i cannot get it from a query). 
The gridView appears and the dropdown list appears. Works fine till now.

The problem is that the filtering using the dropdown (in Value column) doesnt work. (because its not a column from the query output)
    And also the sort on the Value column(when i click on the column header) doesnt work.

Is there a way to get this done? Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get the filter dropdown rendered correctly? As a sidenote: You don't need to supply `$data->id` to `getValue()` as you could use `$this->id` inside that method.

Comment: Side note: In your code, you are passing `$data->id` only on widget creation. If you want it to be filled with record id's then use like that: `'value' => function($data) {return $data->id}`

Comment: The problem is with the filtering and sorting of the Value column. I have edited the question now. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In Model:

```
class Plans extends BasePlans
{
 ...
public $planTypeSearch;
 ...

public function search() {    
...     
$criteria->compare('plan.plan_type', $this->planTypeSearch, true);
...
),
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
            'planTypeSearch'=>array(
                 'asc'=>'plan.plan_type',
                 'desc'=>'plan.plan_type DESC',
             ),
         ),
     ),
 );
```

In your view:

```
array(
    'name'=>'planTypeSearch',
    'header'=> 'Plan Type',
    'value'=>'(isset($data->plan)) ? $data->plan->plan_type: null',
    'filter'=>isset($plans) ? CHtml::listData($plans, 'plan_type','plan_type') : NULL,
),
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Deez. Talking in terms of your example, my situation is that I dont have a column called plan_type in the table Plan, and because of that, I cannot use plan_type in $criteria. I am expecting any alternate solution to sort the data AFTER fetching from the database.

Comment: without knowing what $this->getValue() does its kinda hard to say. If it is performing a mathematical equation from other columns, you can put the same calculation in the sort part of the search function. I have done this with success.

Comment: Thanks Deez. Sorry for my late reply. $this->getValue() is a completely different function(in model) and does not use any columns in this query. This function queries a different table and returns a result. Hope you got my situation. Thanks.